# How to take advantage of each process when using two fork()'s in C

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child

So, I've been trying to understand forks, and although I understand the basics (ie. another process gets created with a copy of the original data when we use `fork()`), I can't really grasp actually doing things with these processes that are created.

For example: I have to write a program that will call `fork()` twice to create 4 processes in total. When one process is created I have to print out the `pid` with `getpid()`. After printing out four ID's, my program is supposed to print a single letter 10 times.

For example, parent 1 will print 'A', child 1 will print 'B', child 2 will print 'C' and the parent of that will print 'D'. To do this, I have to use `putchar(ch);` and flush the output with `fflush(stdout)`.

This means the output will look like this:

```
Process created, ID: 3856
Process created, ID: 3857
Process created, ID: 3858
Process created, ID: 3859
AAAAAABBBBBBBCDCDCDCDCDCDCBBBDCDCAAAADCD
```

So far, I've gotten the four processes to print with this code:

```
 int main(void) {
     pid_t child1, child2;
     child1 = fork();
     child2 = fork();
     printf("Process created. ID: %d\n", getpid());
}
```

But I don't know how to use `wait()` to have everything print out randomly, after I have printed the ids.

To get everything I need to print out to be a "random mess," what should I do? Should I call functions like this?

```
// in main
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    char_parent1();
    char_child1();
    char_parent2();
    char_child2();
}
return 0;
}

void char_parent1()
{
    putchar('A');
    fflush(stdout);
}

void char_child1()
{
    putchar('B');
    fflush(stdout);
}

// and so on for char_parent2() and char_child2()
```

In that case, if my professor says I have to basically print things out concurrently and randomly, then why should I be using `wait()`?

Comment: so where do you print the char? post the code

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which has several chapters to answer your questions.

Comment: @simon_xia I added an example of what I think I should be doing.. possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process needs to know which letter it is supposed to print.  That means you have to analyze the values in `child1` and `child2`.  For example, one process has two zeros; it might print `D`.

Arguably, each process needs to know whether it is a parent or not.  If it is not a parent, it can simply exit after printing 10 copies of its letter, each followed by a `fflush()`.  If it is a parent, after waiting for its children to die, it should exit.  This means that the original process will exit last.  It could usefully output a newline after its last child has died.  You might or might not print diagnostic information about dead children as you go.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I took your advice and got it to work :)